# copy all request attributes in class attributes

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

In my controller I have methods to store and update. As you see, I am copying `$request` attributes in `$tour` attributes one by one:

```
class TourController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request, Tour $tour)
        {
          $tour->name = $request->name;
          $tour->flight = $request->flight;
          $tour->price = $request->price;
          $tour->description = $request->description;
          $tour->save();
          return redirect('home/tour/see');
        }
    public function update(Request $request)
        {
            $tour = Tour::find($request->id);
            $tour->name = $request->name;
            $tour->flight = $request->flight;
            $tour->price = $request->price;
            $tour->description = $request->description;
            $tour->save();
            return redirect('home/tour/see');
        }
}
```

It seems, I'm repeating my code, and my question is, is there a way to copy all of them at once? How to copy all request attributes in tour attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can also Try this:

```
Tour::create($request->all());
```

for more 
[See laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do `$tour = request()->all();` to get all the inputs at the same time

or you could do smth like this:

```
$tour = new Tour;

$tour= save(request()->all());
```

Comment: this makes $tour an array, then you cant call $tour->save() on it

Comment: @AliSeyfi checagain

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which gets all attributes from the request and sets these properties.

```
class TourHydrator

public function updateFromRequest(Request $request, Tour $tour)
{
     $tour->name = $request->name;
     $tour->flight = $request->flight;
     $tour->price = $request->price;
     $tour->description = $request->description;
}
```

Then [inject](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#automatic-injection) it in your controller

```
class TourController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @var TourHydrator
     */
    private $tourHydrator;

    public function __construct(TourHydrator $tourHydrator)
    {
        $this->tourHydrator = $tourHydrator;
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Tour $tour)
    {
        $this->tourHydrator->updateFromRequest($request, $tour);
        $tour->save();
        return redirect('home/tour/see');
    }

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        $tour = Tour::find($request->id);
        $this->tourHydrator->updateFromRequest($request, $tour);
        $tour->save();
        return redirect('home/tour/see');
    }
}
```

I would recommend this approach rather than using `$request->all()` because the request might change as the application evolves.

You can also add [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation) for instance and in your controller you can treat them:

```
try {
    $this->tourHydrator->updateFromRequest($request, $tour);
    $tour->save();
    return redirect('home/tour/see');
} catch (SomeException $e) {
    return redirect('home/tour/invalid');
}
```

I would also recommend using gettest and setters in your `Tour` model because sometimes magic methods can be tricky especially when it comes to testing. Then you could change the `TourHydrator` to use the appropriate setters.